# Mplayer starts very slowly

Tags: pi-zero-w, internet, raspbian-wheezy, processor-speed

I'm using raspberry pi zero w, I generally need to start mplayer again and again in separate times. However, it starts to run really slowly. Is there a way to make its start faster?

I'm using rotary encoder to change radio station having IP:Port(online streaming). mplayer have to use -playlist if station uses .pls or .m3u extetensions. So AFAI research there is no way to create new playlist by using another playlist. I have some IP:Ports when the rotary enocder is turned, the application starts mplayer with address of the station(iterating through one by one). I asked the question to see whether there is wrong thing related to the pi's speed.

On raspberry,

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ time mplayer 
real    0m4.021s
user    0m3.639s
sys     0m0.228s
```

[image]

On ubuntu (my machine),

```
soner@ubuntu:~$ time mplayer
real    0m0.088s
user    0m0.059s
sys     0m0.022s
```

[image]

Comment: I hope you understand that the raspberry pi zero is a single core ARM cpu, running at under 1Ghz with 1GB ram shared with GPU, using a "hard drive" that probably has a 10Mbit max read speed - comparing this with a quad core / 8 thread i7 with 16+GB ram and at least a 6Gbit SSD if not 32Mbit NVMe hard drive is like comparing the speed of a Fiat 500 to a Ferrari LaFerrari for example

Comment: of course, 32Mbit NVme was supposed to be 32**G**bit NVMe :p

Comment: Starting mplayer every 2 minutes seems to be a design failure.